# Select name from one list box to another using add item error

Tags: vba, ms-access, listboxitem

Got an issue where I want to select a text from one list box and add the text into another list box. the error only seems to happen if text has a "'" within the text and VBA seems to split the text and add the remaining text to the next column. Also, I'm working with column in my listbox and my code should add each text from left to right. This is fine but I need the whole text (including the ".") instead of the text being split up.

[image]

```
Private Sub btnAddUser_Click()
        
Dim SelectUser, ItemString1, ItemString2 As String, ItemString3 As String

For Each SelectUser In lstusers.ItemsSelected

    Debug.Print lstusers.Column(0, SelectUser)
    Debug.Print lstusers.Column(1, SelectUser)
    Debug.Print lstusers.Column(2, SelectUser)
    
    ItemString1 = lstusers.Column(0, SelectUser)
    ItemString2 = lstusers.Column(1, SelectUser)
    ItemString3 = lstusers.Column(2, SelectUser)
    
    Form_frmAS.lstAddedUsers.AddItem ItemString1, 0

    Form_frmAS.lstAddedUsers.AddItem ItemString2, 1
    
    Form_frmAS.lstAddedUsers.AddItem ItemString3, 2
    
    Form_frmAS.lstAddedUsers.Requery
    
Next SelectUser       
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make it work or do I need to find a workaround?

Many Thanks

Comment: I am confused. First you say issue is with apostrophe then you mention period. Show sample raw data as text table. Is listbox ColumnCount set to 2? What is ColumnWidths?

Comment: it's for "," sorry about that.

Sample Data:

Full Name
Doe, John
Doe, Jane
Bank, Paker

Comment: Data in your comment does not look like what is in image. Edit question to show data as text table. Are you saying one value is `Doe, John Doe` and another is `Jane Bank, Paker`? And correct the typo.

Comment: I did a test building ValueList string like `"abc, def;ghi, jkl"`, comma and semi-colon are treated same. I don't see any way to get around it other than replacing comma with some other character. Apostrophe and period are not issue.

Answer (score 0):

in the [ListBox.AddItem method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.additem), the second parameter is the position in the list, i.e. the row number and not the column number. You cannot add the columns one by one.

To make it work, set the Row Source Type of the second ListBox to **Value List** and change the code to

```
For Each SelectUser In lstusers.ItemsSelected
    lstAddedUsers.AddItem lstusers.Column(0, SelectUser) & ";" _
        & lstusers.Column(1, SelectUser) & ";" _
        & lstusers.Column(2, SelectUser)
Next
```

If you don't specify the second parameter in `AddItem`, the new item will automatically be appended at the end of the list.

Comment: Whether or not string is broken to multiple columns depends on ColumnCount property and whether or not they display depends on ColumnWidths.

Comment: ColumnCount = 3 and ColumnWidths = 2cm,2cm,2cm

Comment: If the Row Source Type is *Value List*, then commas and semicolon will break the items to the next column, but not the single quote as the OP mentioned. But the *list separator* defined in the Windows regional settings do influence the separator used by Access!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice. Managed to do a work around to join Last Name, "," , first name.